# Angular reactive form - Disabling a required form control makes the form valid even if no value is given

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

I have created an angular reactive form like below

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <h5 class="card-title text-center">Login</h5>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="text-success" for="exampleInputEmail1"
      >Email address</label
    >
    <input
      type="email"
      class="form-control"
      id="exampleInputEmail1"
      aria-describedby="emailHelp"
      formControlName="email"
      placeholder="Enter email"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="text-danger" for="exampleInputPassword1"
      >Password</label
    >
    <input
      type="password"
      class="form-control"
      id="exampleInputPassword1"
      formControlName="password"
      placeholder="Password"
    />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

public loginForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.initializeForm();
}

initializeForm = () => {
  this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
    age: [''],
    email: ['', [Validators.required]],
    password: ['', [Validators.required]],
  });
  this.loginForm.controls.email.disable();
  this.loginForm.controls.password.disable();
}

onSubmit() {
  if (this.loginForm.valid) {
    console.log('Login form - valid');
  } else {
    console.log('Login form - invalid');
  }
}
```

[Fiddle having the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yijlg8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

As you can see I have 3 form control fields inside the form group, `email`, `password` and `age`. `age` is a hidden field, I will update this from my script based on some logic.

I have made my `email` and `password` disabled using `this.loginForm.controls.email.disable();` and `this.loginForm.controls.password.disable();` during the initialization process itself. I will enable them depending on some logic later.

As of now I have 2 required form controls disabled and have not initialized with any value. Ideally this form is not valid. But when I try to log the form valid status in the console from the form submit function, it logs the valid status as true.

Why is this so?

Some other behaviors that I noticed are

- Instead of disabling independent form controls, if we disable the complete form using `this.loginForm.disable();`, the form will stay in invalid state as per my requirement, but this will not be changed to valid if we update the value in form.
- Also if I disable the third input `age` along with the 2 inputs `email` and `password`, the form will stay invalid, but this will not be changed to valid if we update the value in form.
- Also if did not have the third field `age` and I made 2 inputs `email` and `password` disabled, the form will stay invalid, but still this will not be changed to valid if we update the value in form.

Can someone say why the form is valid when some inputs are disabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you disable a form field (form control) it means that the control is exempt from validation checks and excluded from the aggregate value of any parent. Status will be `DISABLED`.

- So in your project, when you disable email/password, and age is still there then your form will be valid cause age is valid.
- In your first bullet, when you disable the whole form, you check if form is valid. Form is not valid nor invalid. Your form will have status `DISABLED`.
- In the second bullet, if you disable all the fields of the form, then form will have status `DISABLED` again cause all fields have this status.
- In the third bullet, both fields disabled means that your form will have `DISABLED` status.

In other words, checking for valid and invalid form is not correct.
Try to use `else if` and add `DISABLED` check for better understanding.

```
  if (this.loginForm.valid) {
    console.log('Login form - valid');
  } else if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
    console.log('Login form - invalid');
  } else if (this.loginForm.disabled) {
    console.log('Login form - disabled');
  }
```

Comment: I understand the form is disabled. But updating the value of a disabled input is not updating the form validity status. This is the strange behaviour that confuses me. Why is this so? I have set the value to form controls, then why its invalid?

Comment: According to my first sentence, by updating/initializing a value of a disabled field the form is not affected.

Comment: You are correct. Angular doesnot consider disabled fields for determinig the valid state of the form or it even dont return the disabled controls in the form value  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#784

Comment: So this is a default functionality/bug of angular. I may need to modify my logic.